# Issue while loading date parameter in DB2 query in ssis

Tags: ssis, db2, oledb, ssis-2012

I have a DB2 query that takes date parameter as input. for some reason, it throws error saying **Numeric Value out of range**.
Date value - 2018-05-21 17:33:56.2463440
little bit of query - [Snapshot from SSIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SRlq.png)

```
" SELECT LPAD(i.abc, 13, '0') AS abc, 
LPAD(i.abc,9,'0') AS abc,
b.abc,
i.abc,
i.abc,
i.abc,
i.abc,
i.abc,
i.abc,
i.abc,
i.abc,
sd.abc

FROM abc.abci  LEFT OUTER JOIN abc.abc b
ON i.abc= b.abc,
abc.abc f 
 INNER JOIN abc.abc v ON
i.abc= v.abc

,abc.abc md,
abc.abc sd
WHERE 
i.abc= 'A'
AND i.abc= 'N'
AND i.abc= 'Y'
AND i.abc= f.abc
AND i.abc= f.abc
AND i.abc= f.abc
AND i.abc=f.abc
AND i.abc= v.abc
AND i.last_update_ts > ?  "
```

last_update_ts  - datatype is - **timestamp(6)** in source.

the above query works when we hard code the date as

**i.last_update_ts > '2018-05-21 17:33:56.2463440'**

But, it is throwing an error when it is passing through a parameter.

Comment: Not the reason, but: Pedantically, timestamps should usually be queried with an inclusive lower-bound (`>=`) and an exclusive upper-bound (`<`).  This is primarily because of how numbers are represented and added, but more practically: you can have multiple updates happen at the same timestamp, so if you didn't get all of them last time, you need to this time.

Comment: Um, your fractional seconds portion is seven digits long, not the six specified by the type.  Perhaps the parameter-replacement version is only expecting 6 to match the actual type of the field (as opposed to auto-casting the constant value).  Does explicitly stating the type of the replacement variable, or using casting?

Comment: It's always useful to indicate your Db2 version and platform and include the entire error message and code(s) verbatim, not just your interpretation of it. Try telling the query compiler what the parameter type is: `AND i.last_update_ts > CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP(6))`