# SQLcode=-302 for some users only

Tags: sql, db2, settings

In our application only one sql query is returning sqlerror=-302 for some users only. When I call function with this Query, it is working fine and for some other users also it is working fine. Only certain users are having issue with this query. 
Queries on other tables in the same schema are working fine and I also checked grants of other tables and the table used in this query all are same, but still query is failing for some users.
Anybody had faced this kind of issue earlier?? please let me know if you were able to find the root cause of the issue.

```
SELECT OCS.OPERATOR_ID, OCS.CHECK_ID, OCS.TEMPLATE_ID, OCS.START_DATE,
    OCS.COMPLETE_DATE, OCS.STATUS, OCS.APPROVER_ID 
  FROM OC_STATUS AS OCS, OC_CHECK 
  WHERE OCS.OPERATOR_ID = [Param.1] 
    AND OCS.OPERATOR_TYPE = [Param.2] 
    AND OC_CHECK.CHECK_NAME = [Param.3] 
    AND OC_CHECK.WORKSTATION = [Param.4] 
    AND OCS.CHECK_ID = OC_CHECK.CHECK_ID 
    AND OCS.TEMPLATE_ID = OC_CHECK.TEMPLATE_ID
```

This query executes on DB2 and We are calling it from Java transaction.

Comment: Please tag this question with the specific database you are using. It's really necessary.

Comment: Also, what's the query. I can't see any.

Comment: What software? How could anyone help you here without knowing that? *must be time for holiday break*

Comment: A similar question was asked yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50517651/issue-while-loading-date-parameter-in-db2-query-in-ssis    try explicitly casting your parameters to the correct data type  e.g. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.embed.doc/doc/t0005862.html

Comment: Also, please use a modern `join` clause. It's not the early 90s anymore.

Answer (score 0):

That error code is usually related to unsuccessful data type conversions. There's a myriad of reasons why that could happen and don't think it's possible to find out if you don't have/provide the specifics.

Having said that my *guesses* are:

- Some of those parameters need to be transformed somehow in order to compare them to the corresponding columns. On some cases, that transformation doesn't work as expected, maybe because a specific value exceeds the precision and/or capacity of the column... or something similar. You should get the specific parameter values and try running the query by hand.
- For some cases (users) maybe the join condition `OCS.TEMPLATE_ID = OC_CHECK.TEMPLATE_ID` or `OCS.CHECK_ID = OC_CHECK.CHECK_ID` have a mismatching data type. Maybe the columns are similar but not exactly the same length, precision, or scale. That can also cause data type transformation errors too. DB2 is notorius for allowing you to compare `varchar` against `integer` or other types.